How do I save entity to MongoDB that does not serialize with getters
I use the Java MongoDB driver to access MongoDB.
I have this example entity class:
public class TestJavaMongoDriverEntityMDO {
    
    @BsonProperty("_id")
    private ObjectId id;
    
    @BsonProperty("val")
    private String val;

    public TestJavaMongoDriverEntityMDO() {
        this.val = null;
    }

    public TestJavaMongoDriverEntityMDO(String val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public String getVal() {
        if (val == null) {
            return "someValue";
        }
        return val;
    }

    public void setVal(String val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public ObjectId getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public void setId(ObjectId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

When I save it to the database with val == null, the result object in MongoDB has value val set to "someValue".
What should I do to serialize the field val as it is - so null, rather than the result of the get action?

Please post the code you use for serializing and storing/loading the data to/from MongoDB. And take a look onto this post https://stackoverflow.com/q/48197150/150978

The MongoDB driver does not use getter and setter methods at all.  It only cares about accessing fields directly.  This is an unfortunate design decision, but that’s how it currently works.

@VGR The behaviour described by the OP suggests it does use the getter, or they are serializing it by a different means.

@MarkRotteveel Oops, my mistake.  I misread the question as wanting to use getters, not as wanting serialization that does not use getters.
